# How to change height of scrollview to not overlap linear layout in android?

Tags: android, scroll, android-linearlayout

I have this xml layout, but the problem is that, in the scroll view, the height of it is spanning the whole screen and overlapping the bottom linear layout (drawing on top of it). Is there a way so that, I can get the scroll view height going only up to the linear layout on the bottom? I want the bottom 2 buttons to be aligned to the bottom of the screen.

Thanks

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".ActivityProfile" >

    <ScrollView 
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/picture_avatar"
                    android:layout_width="90dp" 
                    android:layout_height="310dp"
                    android:background="#bdbdbd"
                    android:src="@drawable/no_avatar" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textview_status"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:text="" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_fullname"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="email"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_phone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="phone" 
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_website"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:autoLink="web"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_bio"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_lastactive"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_datejoined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_dateleft"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_logout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="CloseActivity"
            android:text="@+string/back" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_exit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="GoToEditProfile"
            android:text="@+string/edit" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change it to LinearLayout and use layout_weight :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView 
     android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="0dp" 
     android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture_avatar"
                android:layout_width="90dp" 
                android:layout_height="310dp"
                android:background="#bdbdbd"
                android:src="@drawable/no_avatar" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:text="" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_fullname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="email"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_phone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="phone" 
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_website"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_bio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_lastactive"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_datejoined"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview_dateleft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="CloseActivity"
        android:text="@+string/back" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_exit"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="GoToEditProfile"
        android:text="@+string/edit" />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

hope help you.

Comment: you can also try to change the weight to a higher number like 1.5 to make the scrollview occupy more space

Answer (score 0):

in your linear layout (at the bottom) add it to be situated below the scrollview

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_below=""@+id/scrollView1"   <-- this code
>
```

and also change the main base layout to linearlayout so it wont overlap

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ActivityProfile"
android:orientation='horizontal'
>
```

dont forget to change the tab at the very end

```
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: put it on the 1st linear layout

Comment: nope.. the first linear layout serves as a container for the items inside the scrollview

Comment: this just made the scrollview go on top of the buttons. Now I can't even see the buttons. Is there a way to reduce the height of the scroll view to go upto the bottom linear layout?

Comment: then i think you need to change the main base layout to linearlayout instead of relativelayout

Comment: <ScrollView 
         android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_abovew="@+id/first" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/first"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

try this one is this what you mean?its the first linear